# TypeError: invalid 'in' operand a when using json file

Tags: jquery, json

I have been trying to use the json file to graph the data, however I get the following error. I'm not sure if it is my json file or the coding of the charts which is causing this problem.
The following is the json file:

```
{"Real":{
         "data":[[140238120000,50],[140281680000,200],[140575800000,100],
                 [140584800000,150],[140731740000,140],[140809740000,130],
                 [141112530000,120],[141121560000,90],[141260520000,100]]
        }}
```

The extract of the code

```
var seriesArr = [];
                        $.each('powerdata.json', function (key, data) {
                            var series = {
                                name: key,
                                data: [],
                            };

                            $.each(data.y, function (index, value) {
                                series.data.push({
                                    y: value
                                });
                            });

                        /*  $.each(data.data, function (index, value) {
                                series.data[index] = value;
                            }); */

                            seriesArr.push(series);

                            var seriesValues = {
                                name: series.name,
                                data: series.data,
                                pointInterval: weekInterval,
                                pointStart: Date.UTC(2014, 06, 1, 10, 0, 0)
                            };


                            charts.xAxis[0].axisTitle.attr({
                                text: 'By Week'
                            });

                            charts.addSeries(seriesValues, false);
                            charts.redraw();
                        });
```

---

EDITED VERSION

I have been working on getting the JSON file to graph. The following is what i have tried however i dont see why this will not work

JSON File

```
[{"name": "Real", "data":[["time" : 140238120000, "val":50],["time" : 140281680000, "val":200],["time" : 140575800000, "val":100],["time" : 140584800000, "val":150],["time" : 140731740000, "val":140],["time" : 140809740000, "val":130],["time" : 141112530000, "val":120],["time" : 141121560000, "val":90],["time" : 141260520000, "val":100]]}]
```

Code

```
$.getJSON('data.json', function(aData) {
                        var seriesData = [];
                                $.each(aData.data, function(idx, res) {
                                seriesData.push([res.time, res.val]);
                                });

                                var seriesValues = {
                                        name: aData.name,
                                        data: seriesData,
                                        type: 'spline'
                               }

                            charts.addSeries(seriesValues, false);

                            charts.redraw();
                        });
```

Comment: What is the error? you missed it.

Comment: the error has been mentioned its "TypeError: invalid 'in' operand a".

Answer (score 0):

You pushing items into your object in wrong manner I suppose.

This might be your problem, go for this:

```
$.each(data.y, function (index, value) {
    series.Real.data.push({
        y: value
    });
});
```

If you get problems understanding objects, then use `[]` notation like the above can also be written as:

```
series['Real']['data'].push(...);
```

Comment: i have tried this but still does not work, However when i placed the data in the json as a variable the  code "$.each(data.data, function (index, value) { series.data[index] = value; }); works
        series.data[index] = value;
       });

Comment: @user3523549 Can you please make a JSFiddle then? Can try to find out problem id there is any...

Comment: I have made a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9P5fC/400/ As I mentioned it works with a declared variable but not within a json file.

Comment: If its a only a problem for file not variable then problem must be somewhere else...